# Creating base class for Entities in Entity Framework

Tags: frameworks, entity, radix, data-access-layer, data-access

I would like to create a base class that is somewhat generic for all of my entities. The class would have methods like Save(), Delete(), GetByID() and some other basic functionality and properties. I have more experience with Linq to SQL and was hoping to get some good examples for something similar in the EF. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
public abstract class BaseObject<T>
    {
        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            db.DeleteObject(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            db.AcceptAllChanges();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
     }

    public interface IBaseRepository<T>
    {
        void Add(T entity);

        T GetById(int id);
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    }
```

Comment: What do you do with the interface?

Comment: The class appears to be missing the DBContext object, "db" declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The ADO.NET Entity Framework supports both Table-per-hierarchy and Table-per-type inheritance.  I suggest you start [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/03/15/inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) to see how it works.