# Entity Framework Generic Base Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have no choice in creating a data first Entity Framework implementation.  I want to extend the generated class to include a generic base class that I can call all the basic functions on. (I know how to update the t4 templates)

Update (add if not currently in DB), GetAll, Select (based on parameters) and Delete functions.  I have found a few things that I think may work but they do not have fully qualified namespaces and I can't figure out where the information is stored.

[Creating base class for Entities in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762069/creating-base-class-for-entities-in-entity-framework) - is one such which is basically a duplicate of my question but the answers are not complete.

What would be an example of this base class WITH the fully qualified namespace?

Comment: Just because you're going against an existing database doesn't mean that you can't use Code First. That would prevent having to alter the templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Code First even though you have a database. You can generate your model. Depends what you need, please see 2 different ways to approach the problem.

### Generic repository

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext context;

    protected BaseRepository(MyDbContext context) 
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        // Set<TEntity> provides you an access to entity DbSet
        // Just like if you call context.Users or context.[AnyTableName]
        return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Next you want to implement entity-specific repositories:

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>
{
    public UserRepository(MyDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Simple usage example:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var userRepository = new UserRepository(context);
    var users = userRepository.GetAll();
}
```

### Just put your generic methods in context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    // ... more DbSets

    public List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    // For entities that implement INamedEntity interface
    // with property Name.
    public TNamedEntity FindByName<TNamedEntity>(string name)
        where TNamedEntity : INamedEntity, class
    {
        return Set<TNamedEntity>()
            .FirstOrDefault(entity => entity.Name == name);
    }
}
```

I use nuget package `EntityFramework`. `DbContext` and `DbSet` comes from `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

Hope it's enough for you to get started and implement all the methods that you need.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer so quickly. I have been reading that you should not use the repository pattern with Entity Framework since it basically already has that built in.  Why the double work?  Also I have over 200 tables.  Am I to generate a repository for each table?  I have about 120 tables with the basic structure that I was hoping to use an Interface to generically edit in my WebApi which is why I was looking to use a base class.

Comment: This is a good point. you should mention it all in your question. Let me re-write it a bit for you.

Comment: Thank you!  Also would you be so kind as to provide either the using statements or fully qualified namespace?

Comment: This is great, thank you.  One small problem and it is probably my lack of knowledge on generics.  I am getting the error:  The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'

Comment: @CherylTyme I forgot `class` constraint. Was writing it from my head, sorry :). Please see the update.

Comment: I tried to use the code you provided but I got another compile error.  I changed it to : 
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity :class 
    {
        protected DbContext context;

        protected BaseRepository(MyDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public List<TEntity> GetAll() 
        {
            // Set<TEntity> provides you an access to entity DbSet
            return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }
    }

Is this correct?

Comment: @CherylTyme yeah I think so